# Rails 4 Stylesheets loading (twitter bootstrap and less)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, stylesheet

I try to do some style with Rails 4 and less, and got some problems.
I install some gems into `Gemfile` to get Twitter Bootstrap layout (version 2.x)

```
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

All is working fine, I have this lines into `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.less` (note: I've renamed `.css` into `.css.less` for doing tests, I hope it works)

```
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
```

Then, I installed `selectize.js` plugin ( http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ )

So I put specific less files into `app/assets/stylesheets` :

```
selectize.bootstrap2.less
selectize.less
plugins/*some_less_files*
```

and update `application.css.less` to add

```
*= require selectize.bootstrap2.less
```

When I run my application, I got this error :

```
Showing app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
variable @inputBorderRadius is undefined
  (in app/assets/stylesheets/selectize.bootstrap2.less)
```

The `app/assets/stylesheets/selectize.bootstrap2.less` contains this line :

```
@selectize-border-radius: @inputBorderRadius;
```

I don't understand why it fails, because `@inputBorderRadius` is defined with `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less`, in this file :

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.8/vendor/toolkit/twitter/bootstrap/variables.less
```

And this file is imported by `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less`, which import (gem) file `twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap`, which import (gem) file `twitter/bootstrap/variables.less`

... what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with selectize.js, but it could be the load order in your application.css file is wrong. If you call bootstrap2.css.less before bootstrap_and_overrides it would have no knowledge about @inputBorderRadius.

Btw, this gem might come in handy:https://github.com/manuelvanrijn/selectize-rails. It provides a rails engine for selectize.js. These kind of gems usually solve trouble concerning the asset pipeline.

Comment: I set the right order. It doesn't the validity of some variables using require or import... But the selectize-rails gems works for this problem.